# Html webpage print function does not displaying text box values

Tags: html, printing, textbox

I have tried code for a print option in a div on my webpage. But it is not showing the values entered in the text box. Please help me with the code below or give good references to print div values with values inside the text box.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

    <head>
        <title>10.1 Investment Portfolio Details</title>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            function printDiv(divName) {
                var inpText = document.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value;
                var printContents = document.getElementById(divName).innerHTML;
                var originalContents = document.body.innerHTML;
                document.body.innerHTML = printContents;
                document.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value = inpText;
                window.print();
                document.body.innerHTML = originalContents;
            }
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <input type="button" onclick="printDiv('printableArea')" value="print" />
        <div id="printableArea">
             <h1 style="margin-top:7px; text-align:center;margin-left: 47px;">10 Assets Investment</h1>

            <table border="1" id="10.1" name="10.1" style="margin-top:-8px" class="colsumPortfolio">
                <tr style="background-color:#D8A455; border-top-color: white; border-style: hidden hidden groove;font-size: 24px;font-size: 24px;">
                    <td colspan=6 style="border-right-style: hidden; font-weight:bold;">10.1 Investment Portfolio Details</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>Particulars</th>
                    <th>Outstanding</th>
                    <th>Average</th>
                    <th>Interest & Dividend Earned</th>
                    <th>Income from sale of Investments</th>
                    <th>Yield</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Investments to Total Assets Ratio</td>
                    <td class="tdright">
                        <input type=text>
                    </td>
                    <td class="tdright">
                        <input type=text>
                    </td>
                    <td class="tdright">
                        <input type=text>
                    </td>
                    <td class="tdright">
                        <input type=text>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type=text>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th colspan="6" style="text-align: left;background: white;color: black">Investments in India USD</th>
                    <!-- <td class="tdright"><input type=text id="10.1_2_1" name="10.1_2_1" title="qry"></td>
    <td  class="tdright" ><input type=text id="10.1_2_2" name="10.1_2_2" title="qry"></td>
    <td  class="tdright" ><input type=text id="10.1_2_3" name="10.1_2_3" title="qry"></td>
    <td  class="tdright" ><input type=text id="10.1_2_4" name="10.1_2_4" title="qry"></td>
    <td><input type=text id="10.1_2_5" name="10.1_2_5" title="qry"></td> -->
                </tr>
                <tr class="totalcolor2">
                    <td>&nbsp; &nbsp; I. Government Securities</td>
                    <td class="tdright">
                        <input type=text>
                    </td>
                    <td class="tdright">
                        <input type=text>
                    </td>
                    <td class="tdright">
                        <input type=text>
                    </td>
                    <td class="tdright">
                        <input type=text>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type=text>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; T-Bills</td>
                    <td class="tdright">
                        <input type=text>
                    </td>
                    <td class="tdright">
                        <input type=text>
                    </td>
                    <td class="tdright">
                        <input type=text>
                    </td>
                    <td class="tdright">
                        <input type=text>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type=text>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; Central Government Securities</td>
                    <td class="tdright">
                        <input type=text>
                    </td>
                    <td class="tdright">
                        <input type=text>
                    </td>
                    <td class="tdright">
                        <input type=text>
                    </td>
                    <td class="tdright">
                        <input type=text>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type=text>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; State Government Securities</td>
                    <td class="tdright">
                        <input type=text>
                    </td>
                    <td class="tdright">
                        <input type=text>
                    </td>
                    <td class="tdright">
                        <input type=text>
                    </td>
                    <td class="tdright">
                        <input type=text>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type=text>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="totalcolor2">
                    <td>&nbsp; &nbsp; II. Other Approved Securities (as notified by RBI)</td>
                    <td class="tdright">
                        <input type=text>
                    </td>
                    <td class="tdright">
                        <input type=text>
                    </td>
                    <td class="tdright">
                        <input type=text>
                    </td>
                    <td class="tdright">
                        <input type=text>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type=text>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: `document.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value`, why do you want the value of the button?

Comment: sorry its a mistake.. but still it doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you are trying to do to **print** specific `div` 
First of all use `document.getElementsByID()` and in your code.

Add `printcontents += inpText` before `document.body.innerHTML = printContents;` 
like this:

```
function printDiv(divName){
    var originalContents = document.body.innerHTML;
    var inpText = document.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value;
    var printContents = document.getElementById(divName).innerHTML;
    printContents += inpText;
    document.body.innerHTML = printContents;
    window.print();
    document.body.innerHTML = originalContents;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what exactly you are trying to achieve since your code is a mess and question is unclear, I made this snippet which will take input from a `text field` and print it inside a `div` and then open a `print pop-up`. Use this in your code.
**TIP : ** Give `id` to elements and use `getElementById()` instead of `getElementsByTagName()`

```js
function printInDiv()
{
  var text = document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0].value;
  document.getElementById('printable-Area').innerHTML = text;
  window.print();
}
```

```css
#printable-Area
{
  width: 200px;
  height: 80px;
  background-color: red;
  position: absolute;
  top: 20%;
  left: 20%;
  font-size: 40px;
}
```

```html
<input id = "inp" type = "text" placeholder = "Enter Text"></input>
<button onclick="printInDiv()"> Print </button>
<div id="printable-Area"></div>
```

Comment: Requirement is,in my web pages i have some tables with text boxes.. i tried the code to perform a print operation.. but its does't  showing values inside the text box in print preview..

Comment: Your code has 30 `<input type = "text">` blocks for which you don't have any function defined.

Comment: is there any solution??